# Azure DevOps Pipeline Task Condition expands runtime expression as a string literal rather than expression

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am using Azure DevOps Classic pipeline (NO YAML) and seeing following problem with a task's custom condition evaluation:

## Problem:

I have a group variable `SHOULD_CONTINUE_NEXT_TASK` which defines a runtime expression (see below). The variable is then used in a task as custom condition. When the task is run, the condition expands the variable as a string literal instead of as an expression. I have to use this expression at lots of places so defining it as a variable will be useful. Could somebody please help with identifying what am I doing wrong?

Variable Name:
`SHOULD_CONTINUE_NEXT_TASK`

Variable value:

```
$[or(eq(variables.IGNORE_CHANGES_TRIGGER_AND_FORCE_BUILD, 'true'), eq(variables.CONTINUE_BUILD_PIPELINE, 'Yes'))]
```

Task Log:

```
Evaluating: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['SHOULD_CONTINUE_NEXT_TASK'], True))
Expanded: and(True, eq('$[or(eq(variables.IGNORE_CHANGES_TRIGGER_AND_FORCE_BUILD, ''true''), eq(variables.CONTINUE_BUILD_PIPELINE, ''Yes''))]', True))
Result: False
```

Expected Result:
`variables['SHOULD_CONTINUE_NEXT_TASK']` should be expanded to expression `$[or(eq(variables.IGNORE_CHANGES_TRIGGER_AND_FORCE_BUILD, ''true''), eq(variables.CONTINUE_BUILD_PIPELINE, ''Yes''))]` instead of a string literal (notice commas around it)

Tried almost all the possible combinations for a runtime expression. Even the simplest example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?source=recommendations&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml is not working

i.e.,

```
variables:
  isMain: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')]

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello Stage A!

- stage: B
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isMain, 'true'))
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello Stage B!
      - script: echo $(isMain)
```

EDIT:
It turns out that if I define all variables in an expression into pipeline variables or variable group then the expression is expanded correctly but surprisingly runtime expression was evaluated as soon as pipeline ran so my overridden value was not available to task condition.
i.e,
If I have following in variable group

```
CONTINUE_BUILD_PIPELINE=No
IGNORE_CHANGES_TRIGGER_AND_FORCE_BUILD=false
SHOULD_CONTINUE_NEXT_TASK=$[or(eq($IGNORE_CHANGES_TRIGGER_AND_FORCE_BUILD, 'true'), eq($CONTINUE_BUILD_PIPELINE, 'Yes'))
```

it evaluates to False as soon as the pipeline runs. So, my task that sets `CONTINUE_BUILD_PIPELINE=Yes` based on some logic doesn't work because subsequent tasks that want to use `SHOULD_CONTINUE_NEXT_TASK` they still get pre-evaluated value i.e, `False` which should have been `True` if it really evaluate at runtime.

For now, I am going to evaluate whole `SHOULD_CONTINUE_NEXT_TASK` expression in bash task that sets `CONTINUE_BUILD_PIPELINE=Yes` and set `SHOULD_CONTINUE_NEXT_TASK=Yes` to continue or skip the tasks

Comment: Hi, I am using classic pipeline so I cannot import json (or yaml) because my repository type doesn't allow it. Your variables are identical to mine with the exception to double quotes around them in values. I assume classic UI's variable editor doesn't need any quotes?

Comment: Hi, I am also classic pipeline, and the JSON should be able to import. Please check this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln213.png And yes, I didn't have any quotes on this classic pipeline variable definition. :)

Comment: Please feel free to do a test and let me know the result on your side. :)

Comment: Hi Shahzad, any update of this issue?

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to reply back. I think I found the problem. Some of my variables were output variables set by some tasks which are then used by successor task's custom conditions. I edited my question above to add a note that it works fine if I define all variables in variable group. But this is not what I want so I have moved my expression to each task's custom condition instead of defining it as a variable and reusing.

Answer (score 0):

Import this .json file of pipeline on your side:

```
{
    "options": [
        {
            "enabled": false,
            "definition": {
                "id": "5d58cc01-7c75-450c-be18-a388ddb129ec"
            },
            "inputs": {
                "branchFilters": "[\"+refs/heads/*\"]",
                "additionalFields": "{}"
            }
        },
        {
            "enabled": false,
            "definition": {
                "id": "a9db38f9-9fdc-478c-b0f9-464221e58316"
            },
            "inputs": {
                "workItemType": "Bug",
                "assignToRequestor": "true",
                "additionalFields": "{}"
            }
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "CONTINUE_BUILD_PIPELINE": {
            "value": "Yes"
        },
        "IGNORE_CHANGES_TRIGGER_AND_FORCE_BUILD": {
            "value": "true"
        },
        "SHOULD_CONTINUE_NEXT_TASK": {
            "value": "$[or(eq(variables.IGNORE_CHANGES_TRIGGER_AND_FORCE_BUILD, 'true'), eq(variables.CONTINUE_BUILD_PIPELINE, 'Yes'))]"
        },
        "system.debug": {
            "value": "false",
            "allowOverride": true
        }
    },
    "properties": {},
    "tags": [],
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_apis/build/Definitions/357?revision=7"
        },
        "web": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_build/definition?definitionId=357"
        },
        "editor": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_build/designer?id=357&_a=edit-build-definition"
        },
        "badge": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_apis/build/status/357"
        }
    },
    "jobAuthorizationScope": 2,
    "jobTimeoutInMinutes": 60,
    "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 5,
    "process": {
        "phases": [
            {
                "steps": [
                    {
                        "environment": {},
                        "enabled": true,
                        "continueOnError": false,
                        "alwaysRun": false,
                        "displayName": "PowerShell Script",
                        "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                        "retryCountOnTaskFailure": 0,
                        "condition": "and(succeeded(), eq(variables['SHOULD_CONTINUE_NEXT_TASK'], True))",
                        "task": {
                            "id": "e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1",
                            "versionSpec": "2.*",
                            "definitionType": "task"
                        },
                        "inputs": {
                            "targetType": "inline",
                            "filePath": "",
                            "arguments": "",
                            "script": "# Write your PowerShell commands here.\n\nWrite-Host \"Hello World\"\n",
                            "errorActionPreference": "stop",
                            "warningPreference": "default",
                            "informationPreference": "default",
                            "verbosePreference": "default",
                            "debugPreference": "default",
                            "progressPreference": "silentlyContinue",
                            "failOnStderr": "false",
                            "showWarnings": "false",
                            "ignoreLASTEXITCODE": "false",
                            "pwsh": "false",
                            "workingDirectory": "",
                            "runScriptInSeparateScope": "false"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Agent job 1",
                "refName": "Job_1",
                "condition": "succeeded()",
                "target": {
                    "executionOptions": {
                        "type": 0
                    },
                    "allowScriptsAuthAccessOption": false,
                    "type": 1
                },
                "jobAuthorizationScope": 2
            }
        ],
        "target": {
            "agentSpecification": {
                "identifier": "windows-2019"
            }
        },
        "type": 1
    },
    "repository": {
        "properties": {
            "cleanOptions": "0",
            "labelSources": "0",
            "labelSourcesFormat": "$(build.buildNumber)",
            "reportBuildStatus": "true",
            "fetchDepth": "1",
            "gitLfsSupport": "false",
            "skipSyncSource": "false",
            "checkoutNestedSubmodules": "false"
        },
        "id": "a524447c-3ced-4236-84be-9325516abd5d",
        "type": "TfsGit",
        "name": "0113",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/BowmanCP/_git/0113",
        "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/dev",
        "clean": "false",
        "checkoutSubmodules": false
    },
    "processParameters": {},
    "quality": 1,
    "authoredBy": {
        "displayName": "Bowman Zhu",
        "url": "https://spsprodsea2.vssps.visualstudio.com/A64545e3d-c12d-4c81-b77f-4de83783d9bd/_apis/Identities/af91e22a-cc35-4c8e-8af3-f49c4a1b9b6a",
        "_links": {
            "avatar": {
                "href": "https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.ZGU3N2NiY2YtZTgzYy03ZDkwLWI0YTYtOTk3Nzg3NDczMzBl"
            }
        },
        "id": "af91e22a-cc35-4c8e-8af3-f49c4a1b9b6a",
        "uniqueName": "xxx@xxx.com",
        "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.ZGU3N2NiY2YtZTgzYy03ZDkwLWI0YTYtOTk3Nzg3NDczMzBl",
        "descriptor": "aad.ZGU3N2NiY2YtZTgzYy03ZDkwLWI0YTYtOTk3Nzg3NDczMzBl"
    },
    "drafts": [],
    "queue": {
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/_apis/build/Queues/18"
            }
        },
        "id": 18,
        "name": "Azure Pipelines",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/_apis/build/Queues/18",
        "pool": {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Azure Pipelines",
            "isHosted": true
        }
    },
    "id": 357,
    "name": "Variable Condition Demo",
    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6/_apis/build/Definitions/357?revision=7",
    "uri": "vstfs:///Build/Definition/357",
    "path": "\\",
    "type": 2,
    "queueStatus": 0,
    "revision": 7,
    "createdDate": "2022-11-04T02:36:10.260Z",
    "project": {
        "id": "c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6",
        "name": "BowmanCP",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/_apis/projects/c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6",
        "state": 1,
        "revision": 178,
        "visibility": 0,
        "lastUpdateTime": "2022-09-05T06:02:02.693Z"
    }
}
```

I think there should be some mistakes on your side.

You can design your Classic pipeline based on the classic pipeline I provided.

Run successfully on my side:

[image]

I can also make the task skip with the correct format:

[image]